# R Shiny promise/future blocks process

Tags: r, shiny, promise

I cannot figure out the fault in my script's logic that causes Shiny process blocking despite trying to use async `future` + `promises` strategy.

I have this (simplified) server script. It works in principle, but I don't experience parallelization. I simulate 2 simultaneous triggering and the second triggering event waits until the first one resolves.

**Can you please indicate what is wrong here?** I have read several manuals, but I still find it hard to nail down the logic.

Minimal Example, a one-file Shiny app:

```
## load libs

library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- navbarPage(
     tabPanel(
          "Новостные тренды"
          , sidebarLayout(
               sidebarPanel(
                    br()
                    , actionButton(
                         "run_trends"
                         , label = "run"
                         , style="color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4"
                    )
                    , br()
               )
               , mainPanel(
                    textOutput("trends_time")
                    , br()
                    , br()
                    , plotOutput('trend_plotly')
                    , br()
                    , p("results")
                    , br()
                    , DTOutput('trend_tbl')
                    , br()
                    , br()
               )
          )
     )
)

server <- function(input, output, session)
{

     dt_trend <- observeEvent(
          input$run_trends,
          {

               ## load libs

               library(data.table)
               library(ggplot2)
               library(promises)
               library(future)

               plan(multiprocess)

               dat_func <- function()
               {

                    start_time <- Sys.time()

                    dt <- data.table(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100))

                    trendy_tbl <- head(dt, 10)

                    ggplo1 <- ggplot(dt) + geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y))

                    Sys.sleep(10)

                    list(
                         trendy_tbl
                         , ggplo1
                         , paste0('time: ', round(Sys.time() - start_time), ' сек.')
                    )
               }

               f <- future({
                    dat_func()
               })

               #res <- future::value(f)

               output$trend_tbl <- renderDT({future::value(f)[[1]]})

               output$trend_plotly <- renderPlot({future::value(f)[[2]]})

               output$trends_time <- renderText({future::value(f)[[3]]})

          })

}



# Return a Shiny app object
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server, options = list(port = 4600, host = '0.0.0.0'))
```

Comment: Please add a min reprex

Comment: @EliBerkow, thank you. I added a reproducible example. It does not parallel when triggered from different machines simultaneously.

Comment: `future::value` is blocking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(promises)
library(future)

plan(multiprocess)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

     dt_trend <- eventReactive(
          input$run_trends,
          {
               dat_func <- function() {

                    start_time <- Sys.time()
                    dt <- data.table(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100))
                    trendy_tbl <- head(dt, 10)
                    ggplo1 <- ggplot(dt) + geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y))
                    Sys.sleep(10)
                    list(
                         trendy_tbl
                         , ggplo1
                         , paste0('time: ', round(Sys.time() - start_time), ' сек.')
                    )
               }

               # Returning future
               future({
                    dat_func()
               })
     })

     output$trend_tbl <- renderDT({dt_trend()[[1]]})
     output$trend_plotly <- renderPlot({dt_trend()[[2]]})
     output$trends_time <- renderText({dt_trend()[[3]]})

}
```

The key ideas are:

- Make sure you use `shiny` version > 1.1.0 (April 2018) which introduced async support.
- do NOT use `future::value` as it blocks and waits for the future, precisely what we want to avoid.
- instead, return the future in a `reactive`. In this case, this means using `eventReactive` instead of `observeEvent`.
- Access the value of the future via the reactive. Note that your reactive value is now a future! This means you need to use future handlers to use the value. (*)
- You can also return a future in any `renderXXX` function. Useful for example if you have large time-consuming plots.

(*) In practice, this means you need to do

```
renderDT(dt_trend() %>% then(~.[[1]]))
# or 
renderDT(dt_trend() %>...% `[[`(1))
```

where `then` is from the `promises` package and `[[` is the subsetting function from base R (`x[[i]]` is actually semantic sugar for`` `[[`(x, i) `` !).

In your example, you basically compute everything in a single `future` in `dt_trend`. You may want to consider using multiple small futures instead. You can load the data in a reactive with a future, then keep the output code in your `renderXXX` functions, wrapped in a `future` if needed.

There is a good vignette on using promises with shiny available by running `vignette("shiny", package = "promises")`(**). It is also available online on [cran](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/promises/vignettes/shiny.html) or on the [rstudio blog.](https://rstudio.github.io/promises/articles/shiny.html)

(**) If you installed promises with `install_github("rstudio/promises")`, you most likely have to re-install with `build_vignettes = TRUE` first.

Comment: Thank you! Tomorrow I will follow your advices and try this solution. I will let you know....

Comment: FYI I have added a link to a very useful vignette which covers how to use futures in shiny.

Comment: sooo, I tried this strategy, and nope, it does not work, I get an error like this: "wrong arguments for subsetting an environment". I think I got it in my experiments before (and I did use eventReactive...). Somewhere I found this error might be triggered by the fact I do several object output as a list. Can you suppose more options? My shiny ver is 1.3.2.

Comment: Yes, I forgot the most important detail: you access a future via a promise handler. It is very easy in a pipe: instead of piping with `%>%`, you use the magic `%>...%`. To subset (`[[1]]`) in a pipe, you can use the `\`[[\`` function, with the ticks. `renderDT( dt_trend() %>...% \`[[\`(1) )`. This is all much clearer in the vignette!

Comment: I got it, works well!. Yes, I was confused also with nadling future values, and you got me clarified. I read that vignette, but still could not get why I need the piping... THANKS.